# torch.pow does not work

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I'm trying to create a custom loss function using PyTorch, and am running into a simple error.

When I try to use torch.pow to take the exponent of a PyTorch Variable, I get the following error message:

AttributeError: 'torch.LongTensor' object has no attribute 'pow'

In the python terminal, I created a simple Variable, and attempted to do the same, and received the same error. Here's a snippet that should recreate the problem:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np

v = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])))
torch.pow(v, 2)
```

I can't find any information on this issue, and nothing is showing up in search results. Help?

EDIT: this problem also occurs when I try to use torch.sqrt()
EDIT: same problem also happens if I try to do

```
v.pow(2)
```

pow is definitely a method of v, and the docs clearly state that pow is a method that exists and takes a tensor as it's argument. I really don't see how this is happening, and it seems to me that the docs are just flat out wrong and these methods don't actually work.

Comment: What happens if you create the array with `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]` instead of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the tensor as floats, because `pow` always returns a Float.

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np

v = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype="float32")))
torch.pow(v, 2)
```

You can cast it back to integers afterwards

```
torch.pow(v, 2).type(torch.LongTensor)
```

yields

```
Variable containing:
  1
  4
  9
 16
[torch.LongTensor of size 4]
```

Comment: yup! This is it! Thanks!

Comment: same thing here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/attributeerror-torch-cuda-longtensor-object-has-no-attribute-dot/8674